# saving raw audio data to mp3 or a similar format

Tags: java, android, audio-recording

In my android app, am trying to split stereo audio input that I get from AudioRecord class, into two mono channels. Basically I need to work separately with the audio inputs from the two mics, and hence the splitting. I do this by picking alternate samples(2 bytes at a time) of the returned data from audioRecord.read method, and saving it in 2 separate DOUBLE type arrays - ArrayL and ArrayR.
Now I need to save these 2 arrays in such a way as to be able to play it as mono recorded channels, say in .mp3 format.
Is there a simple way to achieve this conversion from double array to any popular audio format and save it on external storage as L and R channel recordings?
Please help out!
Thanks in advance,
Neetha

Answer (score -1, accepted):

steps:

1. Use `read(byte[] audioData, int offsetInBytes, int sizeInBytes)` to get audio into a byte array.
2. Separate two channels by copying every other byte into two different byte arrays.
3. Save two byte arrays as a mp3
4. Play any of them.

for step 3,4

```
String path = "path to new mono mp3 file";
File mp3File = new File(path);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mp3File) ;
fos.write(byteArray);
fos.close();

mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),Uri.fromFile(mp3File));
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Thanks Anuruddha, I tried this i my code. I am facing some other bugs because of which I am unable to test this! Thanks alot for your answer. I am marking this as answered. Hopefully I will soon be able to fix the issue and proceed.

Comment: Writing raw audio data from a byte array without encoding to a file with the extension ".mp3" added on the end will not work. You need to encode your audio data.